# Asp.net need Simultaneous display in Second Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two text boxes I need a functionality like If I am typing in 1st text box The text should be getting displayed in 2nd text Box with some other font. This is a web Application. And so Text Box doesn't have OnKeyDown event? Do you suggest any way to implement this?

**Note:** I don't want to implement this with Javascript.

Comment: This is something you would do in Javascript

Comment: I don't think this is specific to asp.net or c#, and is almost certainly a duplicate of many other questions, try searching  using the search box at the top right and you'll probably find the answer :-)

Comment: What if I don't want to use JavaScript??

Comment: @Chetan You have scripting alternatives but to support the widest array of browsers the common (and most logical choice) would be javascript.

Comment: @Chetan, why don't you want to use Javascript, it's the easiest answer! :-)

Comment: Define "don't want to implement this with javascript'. Just this function or no Javascript in the page whatsoever, which implies you won't be using jQuery or AJAX either.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want to use Javascript, you could wrap both textboxes within an AJAX UpdatePanel and use the TextChanged event of the first TextBox to trigger an update of the second TextBox. Technically speaking, this still results in JavaScript code being created, but it is managed by the AJAX Control Toolkit, so you don't have to touch any of it.

Comment: @Chetan As suggested by Dillie-O, I've updated my answer to include a solution using an `asp:UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution using an `asp:UpdatePanel`

With this approach, you don't need to write a single line of JavaScript by yourself; everything is handled by the control.

*Page.aspx*:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text1" OnTextChanged="text1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text2" class="special"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Event handler for the `TextChanged` event, *Page.aspx.cs*:

```
protected void text1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    text2.Text = text1.Text;
}
```

#### Solution using ASP.NET and jQuery

*Page.aspx*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //As soon as the DOM is ready, execute the anonymous function
    $(function () {
        var textBox1 = $("#<%= text1.ClientID %>");
        var textBox2 = $("#<%= text2.ClientID %>");
        textBox1.keyup(function () {
            textBox2.val(textBox1.val());
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text2" class="special"></asp:TextBox>
```

CSS for both approaches:

```
 .special { font-family: YourFontFamilyOfChoice; }
```

#### Test Results

I've tested both solutions locally with Firefox 3.6, Opera 10.6, and Internet Explorer 8; both work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (JavaScript) combined with CSS. This solution will not trigger a post-back: Your users will see stuff happen as they type.

CSS:

```
.normalFont { font-family: Arial; }
.alternateFont { font-family: Verdana; }
```

HTML:

```
<input ... class="normalFont" />
<input ... class="alternateFont" />
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
// When the DOM is ready, execute anonymous function
$(function ()
{
    // store a reference for the input with the "alternateFont" class
    var alternateFontInput = $("input.alternateFont")[0];

    // execute anonymous function on key-up event on the input with
    // the "normalFont" class
    $("input.normalFont").keyup(function ()
    {
        // set the value of the input with the "alternateFont" class to
        // the value of the input with the "normalFont" class (this)
        alternateFontInput.value = this.value;
    });
});
```